# How to test for specific effects in a linear regression with two categorical covariates and their interaction?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction, interpretation, contrasts

I have a data set with a continuous response variable and two categorical covariates. Let's imagine that I worked at an e-commerce company and was trying to regress the revenue we get from each user as a function of customer type ('A', 'B', 'C'), whether they were exposed to a specific treatment ('Exposed', 'Control'), and the interaction between those two variables.

I would fit the following model, in which a type A customer in the Control group would be used as the reference:

```r
model <- lm(revenue ~ 1 + customer_type * treatment, data = users)
```

In math:
$$
\operatorname{revenue}_i=\beta_0+\beta_1\operatorname{TypeB}_i+\beta_2\operatorname{TypeC}_i+\beta_3\operatorname{Exposed}_i+\beta_4(\operatorname{TypeB}\times\operatorname{Exposed})_i+\beta_5(\operatorname{TypeC}\times\operatorname{Exposed})_i
$$

The question I'm trying to answer is: **is the revenue of type C customers who are exposed to treatment different from the revenue of type C customers who are *not* exposed to treatment?**

The way I tried to figure this out is by deriving what the models would be for the two types of users. That is, for a type C customer who is exposed to treatment, the model becomes

$$
\operatorname{revenue}=\beta_0+\beta_2+\beta_3+\beta_5
$$

and for a type C customer who is *not* exposed, the model is

$$
\operatorname{revenue}=\beta_0+\beta_2
$$

Thus, the difference between the two is not a single parameter but two ($\beta_3+\beta_5$). This means that there isn't a single t-statistic and associated p-value in the regression output that tests the question I have.

Intuitively, I think this must be possible and I probably have the answer right in front of me. What am I missing? Is the solution to use bespoke contrasts (if so, how would I do that in R?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you thus want is to test the hypothesis that the contrast $\beta_3 + \beta_5=0$. You take the ratio of $\beta_3 + \beta_5$ to the standard error of that sum to get the *t*-statistic for testing.

You get that standard error with the [formula for the variance of a weighted sum of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables), which in this case is just the sum of the individual variances plus twice their covariance, then taking the square root. Those (co)variances can be found with `vcov(model)`. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/446676/28500) has some examples.

It's good to know how these calculations are done, but if you are doing a lot of regression work you should learn how to let tools provided by packages like [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) and [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) do the calculations for you.

Comment: Thank you, @EdM! I have been able to do it in two ways: (1) deriving the standard error of the sum manually, and (2) using `multcomp::glht`. Would you mind editing your answer or sharing some resource so I can learn how to do this with `emmeans`?

Comment: @AdriàLuz there's a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) on contrasts and comparisons in `emmeans`, and [another vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html#contrasts) specifically about interactions. For the simple task you asked about, `emmeans` might not provide any advantage over the methods you used. It's very useful when you are looking at several comparisons from a model. It also can make a different type of comparison; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/594253/28500).

Comment: @AdriàLuz this [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/interactions-r/) might also be of interest for how to use `emmeans` to evaluate models with interactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EdM. I found this UCLA article an _excellent_ read!